# Pansharpening Planet multispectral satellite imagery with UAV RGB imagery in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, satellite, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, pansharpening

I'm currently attempting to perform a Gram-Schmidt pansharpening algorithm in ArcGIS Pro using PlanetScope multispectral imagery and UAV-based RGB imagery. I am encountering an issue where the algorithm "succeeds" but the output image is essentially just the Planet imagery without any visible pansharpening having occurred.

Here is my process:

1. Simulate a panchromatic band of the RGB UAV imagery using the average weights of each band (R+G+B/3).
2. Use the 'Create Pansharpened Raster Dataset' tool with the following parameters:

Input Raster: Planet satellite imagery (R,G,B,IR channels)

Panchromatic Image: The simulated single-band panchromatic UAV imagery calculated previously.

Pan-sharpening Type: Gram-Schmidt

Sensor: Unknown, using default weights of R: 0.166, G: 0.167, B: 0.167, IR: 0.5

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

I've ensured my two images are projected to the same CRS and are aligned.